# Сервер добавляет тело запроса в ответ

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, docker

Я разрабатываю API с использованием NGINX, Laravel PHP, MySQL.
Я столкнулся с очень неприятной проблемой и уже битые сутки пытаюсь ее решить.
Почему-то сервер в ответ возвращает тело запроса вместе с ответом. Иногда это происходит на каждый **второй**! запрос.
Я замтеил, что эта проблема пропадает после того как я перезапущу свой php-fpm контейнер. Однак опустя некоторое время снова возвращается.

Этой проблемы не видно, когда я использую Postman для тестирования своего API, но если использовать CURL, то проблема становится видна. Соответственно на клиенте (мобильное приложени) такая же проблема.
Я уже находил подобный вопрос в Google, однако советы мне не помогли. Сам вопрос [ТУТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960375/nginx-prepends-response-data-with-post-request-body-content-from-its-buffer)
На скриншоте 1 будет пример данной проблемы при использовании CURL.

Я не знаю, что мне делать и как избавиться от этого уже несколько дней..

Моя кофигурация NGINX:

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /dev/stdout;
  error_log /dev/stderr;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
  open_file_cache off;
  charset UTF-8;

  map $http_user_agent $limit_bots {
       default 0;
         ~*(google|bing|yandex|msnbot) 1;
         ~*(AltaVista|Googlebot|Slurp|BlackWidow|Bot|ChinaClaw|Custo|DISCo|Download|Demon|eCatch|EirGrabber|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|SuperHTTP|Surfbot|WebWhacker) 1;
         ~*(Express|WebPictures|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE|FlashGet|GetRight|GetWeb!|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It|GrabNet|Grafula|HMView|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It) 1;
         ~*(rafula|HMView|HTTrack|Stripper|Sucker|Indy|InterGET|Ninja|JetCar|Spider|larbin|LeechFTP|Downloader|tool|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|tAkeOut|WWWOFFLE) 1;
         ~*(GrabNet|NetSpider|Vampire|NetZIP|Octopus|Offline|PageGrabber|Foto|pavuk|pcBrowser|RealDownload|ReGet|SiteSnagger|SmartDownload|SuperBot|WebSpider) 1;
         ~*(Teleport|VoidEYE|Collector|WebAuto|WebCopier|WebFetch|WebGo|WebLeacher|WebReaper|WebSauger|eXtractor|Quester|WebStripper|WebZIP|Wget|Widow|Zeus) 1;
         ~*(Twengabot|htmlparser|libwww|Python|perl|urllib|scan|Curl|email|PycURL|Pyth|PyQ|WebCollector|WebCopy|webcraw) 1;
    }

server {
   location / {
       if ($limit_bots = 1) {
           return 403;
       }
}
  }
}
```

**mysitre.conf**

```
server {

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.ca-bundle;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

server_name myapp.com;
root /var/www/myapp/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
    log_not_found off;
}
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_log /var/log/nginx/makeoffer_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/makeoffer_access.log;
}
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --update add logrotate \
    && apk add --no-cache openssl \
    && apk add --no-cache bash

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

RUN set -x ; \
    addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
    adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000

RUN touch /var/log/messages

COPY logrotate/nginx /etc/logrotate.d/

RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server ${PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}:${PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf \
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 443
```

Моя конфигурация PHP-FPM:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

MAINTAINER svinpauk78@gmail.com

ENV COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT='-1'

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libz-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        openssh-server \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        git \
        cron \
        nano \
        libxml2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        mariadb-client \
        unzip \
        jpegoptim \
        optipng \
        pngquant \
        gifsicle \
        supervisor

RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp

#####################################
# PHPRedis:
#####################################
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

#####################################
# Imagick:
#####################################

RUN pecl install imagick && \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick

#####################################
# GD:
#####################################

# Install the PHP gd library
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd

#####################################
# Composer:
#####################################

# Install composer and add its bin to the PATH.
RUN curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/var/www/vendor/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
# Source the bash
RUN . ~/.bashrc

#####################################
# Supervisor :
#####################################
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Final Touch
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

ADD ./laravel.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/myapp

EXPOSE 9001
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

**supervisor.conf**

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:laravel-queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/myapp/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laravel-queue.log
startsecs = 0

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

[image: Скриншот1]

Comment: Я на 99% уверен что проблема в коде, а не в окружении.

Comment: Не могу согласиться с вами

Comment: @Vanya228 проблема в коде, NGINX отдачей запроса не занимается

Comment: @DanilaVershinin я добавил exit() в начало файла index.php. Все равно возвращается тело запроса. Все еще думаете, что дело в коде?

Comment: @Vanya228 по какой ссылке? `/index.php` ?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin может у вас [auto-prepend-file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) настроен?

Answer (score 0):

Причиной моей проблемы являлось наличие вирусов на моем сервере.
Данные вирусы попали на сервер из-за того, что я неверно настроил доступы к директориями и файлам своего проекта на сервере.
Также пришлось скрыт ьпорт php-fpm, чтобы он не показывался снаружи.